# "No input registered" when attempting to start Ubuntu live USB

Tags: system-installation

I have a desktop with Windows 10. I need to install Ubuntu or launch it using USB. But when I try to do either of those  things, I read

> no input registered

Then the display is locked on the Ubuntu logo with 3 points.

- CPU: ryzen 7 3700x
- GPU: rx 5700xt
- RAM: 16gb ddr4 corsair
- Mobo: msi b450 a pro

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Installation, as per Canonical, Ubuntu's publishers, is typically done following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

If you followed those steps, see the suggestion of *Pilot6* in the comment above.